# How to generate def file from singularity container, sif file or sandbox?

Tags: docker, containers, singularity-container

So I have created a singularity sif file, by building it from a writable sandbox. I manually installed the packages and software and other changes in writable mode. But now I want a def file from it. Is there any way?
I have tried  cat /.singularity.d/Singularity but it only shows the build from the def files only not the manual installations.

Comment: If anyone could help me it would be great?

Answer (score 0):

Much like Docker, the singularity container does not keep a record of what you did while inside it. You could check out `~/.bash_history` or `/root/.bash_history` to see if the commands are present there. Otherwise you'll have to rebuild from memory.